# Beginner trying to learn how Aggregation works

Tags: mongodb-query

Last thing in our SQL Beginners course was to tip our toes on few other DB:s and I chose MongoDB. The last and the "Hardest" thing I can do as bonus round is to turn this sqlite command to MongoDB collection line.

```
sqlite> SELECT ore, COUNT(*), MAX(price) FROM Database GROUP BY ore;
```

I created the DB with these values:

```
db.Database.insertMany( [
      { biome: "Desert", ore: "Silver", price: 8000 },
      { biome: "Forest", ore: "Gold", price: 5000 },
      { biome: "Meadow" , ore: "Silver", price: 7000 },
      { biome: "Swamp", ore: "Bronze", price: 6000 },
      { biome: "Mountains", ore: "Gold", price: 9000 },
      { biome: "Arctic" , ore: "Gold", price: 6500 }
      ] )
```

So yeah... I have been reading about pipelines and aggregation operations, but it is flying over my head xP. This is not vital for this course but I would love to learn how this goes. My school has very bad habit of teaching everything in our native language, even if no one in their right minds would ever use that terminology in real life. This makes it sometimes extra hard for me to learn these things while trying to study on my own. If anyone want to give any examples I would be grateful!

End result should look something like this:

```
sqlite> SELECT ore, COUNT(*), MAX(price) FROM Database GROUP BY ore;
ore         COUNT(*)    MAX(price)
----------  ----------  -----------
Silver      2           8000      
Bronze      1           6000       
Gold        3           9000
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the `$group` stage.

The `$group` stage is used to group multiple documents in a collection based on one or many keys. [You can learn more about this pipeline stage here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/).

You will mention the keys you want to group by in the `_id` key of the Group stage.
all the rest of the keys are user-defined with can be accumulated with MongoDB's built-in operators.
In your case, you can make use of the `$sum` operator and pass in the value `1` to add one value to the user-defined `count` key for each document grouped.
And to find the max price, make use of the `$max` key and pass in  `$price` (note `$` prefix since you are self-referencing a key in the source document) to get the max value of a single group.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$ore",
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      },
      "max": {
        "$max": "$price"
      }
    },
  },
])
```

[Mongo Playground Sample Execution](https://mongoplayground.net/p/USY1oUKQkk-)

Comment: Thanks. This was useful. Came back after break today and this helped me to understand how $ worked.

Comment: Glad it helped you out. Don't hesitate to ask more doubts in this comment section